# Can I edit a link to a .exe's target

Tags: permissions, wine, directory

I recently installed the original Half Life and was installing a mod for it when I encountered a problem. The tutorial for installing the mod says to create a short-cut to the original hl.exe and add the "-game hlspbunny" to the end of the link target parameter, so I created a link to hl.exe and opened it's properties only to find that I could not edit the target parameter or anything besides the name and icon. After finding this out I immediately went to the permissions tab and made sure that I could read and write it but even when I had set it to "Read and write" I still could not change the parameter. I have been around on quite a few topics but I couldn’t seem to get a straight answer out of any of them. I'm starting to get a bit frustrated so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps did you create *the link*, i.e. not a shortcut? [Shortcut and link are different things](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470758/symbolic-links-vs-windows-shortcuts), you need to create a script as per answer given below.

Comment: The tutorial that I was viewing was for windows seeing as there where no Ubuntu ones that I could find. In the tutorial it says to create a shortcut and I assumed the Ubuntu equivalent was a "link." Either way I'm trying the answer given down below, I'll comment on the answer below the results so others know whether or not this solution works for me atleast.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to run the hl.exe with "-game hlspbunny" parameter, so you can do this in the command line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>): `LINK_OF_THE_HL_DIR/hl.exe -game hlspbunny`

And it can be converted into a script, save the following content into a file, e.g. HL-mod.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
LINK_OF_THE_HL_DIR/hl.exe -game hlspbunny
```

Remember to change the "LINK_OF_THE_HL_DIR" correspondingly.

And change the permission to make it executable `chmod u+x HL-mod.sh`

Now you can simply run the script to start it.

Comment: "Fatal Error: Failed to initialize authentication interface. Exiting." The terminal reads:  fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 7c088 (device=7 access=3 func=22 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 7c088 (device=7 access=3 func=22 method=0)
err:secur32:SECUR32_initSchannelSP TLS library not found, SSL connections will fail
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
CSteamMatchMaking::~CSteamMatchMaking

Comment: That Error above occurs after I enter the first command line you said to use. I might be doing something wrong but as far as I know I did it right. sorry for my lack of understanding when it comes to Ubuntu I'm extremely new.

Comment: @Gmate You can try to start hl first, run `LINK_OF_THE_HL_DIR/hl.exe` in a terminal, if you can start HalfLife with it, then you will be able to narrow down the problem to the mod.